# Hiding a superview without hiding its subviews

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, hidden, subview, superview

generally I know there are workarounds for this, but is there any simple way in the iOS SDK to hide a superview without hiding its subviews?

I have a parent view that is a background to a few other views. I would like to hide the parent, either through setting its transparency to 0, or setting "hidden" or something - the issue is that these changes affect all of the subviews of the parent.

Again, I realize that there is usually a way around this, but in this case I am dealing with a mapView, and my subviews are annotations and overlays.

Thanks, -Matt

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Yes, a MKMapView will have several layers in it with rendering, so setting backgroundColor wont work.  You could try subclassing MKMapView to add a property to toggle these layers on/off (by removing/re-adding them to the view.)  But this seems pretty dangerous.

You could try setting the MKMApView's "clipsSubviews" to NO/FALSE, and reset the frame to 0,0,0,0.  But this will impact your ability to get Touch events to your subviews.

It's likely a better solution to re-evaluate your view hierarchy.  Make it something like:

```
main-view
  map-view
  transparent-view
    control-1
    control-2
    etc.
```

**Original**

Set the backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: I guess I should be more clear - this specific situation is dealing with MKMapView as the parent view. It doesn't seem that you can just set the background color to clear - nothing really happens :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `backgroundColor` property of the super view to `.clear` and this will have no effect on the appearance of the subview.

```
superView.backgroundColor = .clear
```